# Early 2009 iMac just doesn't detect Windows 7 DVD

Tags: windows, bootcamp

I'm trying to install Windows 7 on an early 2009 iMac and I have a Windows installer DVD, but when I put it in while OS X El Capitan is running, it just makes a few weird sounds for about a minute and then ejects it. It does detect it when I'm in the startup manager, but when I'm in macOS, it just doesn't. Now I can't get past the “Save Windows support software” screen. Does anyone know why?
(I already have support software on a USB.)

Comment: Might help if you could include which version of OS X/macOS you have installed.

Comment: OS X El Capitan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like Parallels or VMware to allow Windows to run "inside" OS X.

Or you install Boot Camp and install Windows so your machine has two systems where you choose one during the boot process.

Comment: Wait, I just got an idea and I wanted to know if this would work:
since I already have the support software on a usb, could I uncheck the support software stuff and it would install?

Comment: No @bwr99 you need virtualization or Boot Camp to give windows a foothold on the Mac hardware. Windows doesn’t support full installation without help on any Mac yet.

Comment: I fixed the issue and I’m gonna post my answer to how.

Comment: I’m gonna check this answer anyways since making a vm would be helpful and run great on high end silicon macs

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by just putting in the dvd before startup.

Comment: Did you get Windows installed?

Comment: Yes,
I need to make the comment longer in order to post it